# Windows 8 display clock

Tags: windows-8, clock

I just got a windows8 laptop and I noticed that the clock is displayed in two areas.

1) Desktop - Task bar
2) Lock Screen.

If I have to see the time, I have to keep switching between the desktop and the task bar.

Can I make the taskbar visible across all apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in 'Modern UI' apps, you should not be using the taskbar. The 'new' place to find the clock is in the Charms bar, which can be opened by *one of* the following:

- Hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a keyboard, *or*
- Moving the cursor to one of the right corners and swiping down the side, *or*
- Dragging in one of the right corners with your finger on a touchscreen

It should display a clock on the lower left and a bar on the right side:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35i0e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may be in kiosk mode when you have apps open. You can press f11 to toggle it. Also, if you upgraded from a previous version of windows, it may be an upgrade issue where the taskbar is not always on top. Try creating a new account and see if the new account has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another method apart from the one Bob mentioned is to hold <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. (That's a comma) This is peek at desktop and works from Desktop/Metro and hence you take a quick glance at the taskbar for the time. Note that is similar to the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut in Windows 7.